# How to run a function each minute in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game in JavaScript, but in the class power ups, I want to create a power up each minute. The problem is that it's called in the `update` method of the class, and this is called each frame in the main update, so once it runs, it doesn't stop again and keeps looping. How can I make it stop and start again?

I was trying with getting the seconds like this:

Method create power up:

```
let time = new Date.getSeconds();
if (time >=59) {create power up}
```

Method update of the power up class:

```
this.createpowerup();
```

Now in the main class I call all update methods from the classes that I have:

```
update() {
    this.player_spaceship_object.update();    
    this.enemy_spaceship_object.update();
    this.power_up_object.update();
    this.movebackground();
}
```

So each frame it will be calling them, but the problem is when power up ends in zero, it creates a lot of power ups until it starts 1, theres like milliseconds to start 1, how can do this in a loop?

Power up class:

```
class Power_ups extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
constructor(scene) {
    super(scene, scene.player_spaceship.x, scene.player_spaceship.y, "power_up");
    //this.hi();
}
hi() {
    setInterval(this.hola,5000);
}
hola() {
    console.log("hola");
}
update() {
    this.hi();
}
}
```

Main class, this is the class that runs once enter to the page:

```
class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene {
constructor() {
    super("Scene2");
}
create() {
    this.scoreText;
    this.timedEvent;
    this.background = this.add.tileSprite(0,0,globalThis.config.width,globalThis.config.height,"space");
    this.background.setOrigin(0,0);
    this.player_spaceship = this.physics.add.sprite(globalThis.config.width/2-50,globalThis.config.height/2,"player_spaceship");
    this.player_spaceship_object = new Player_spaceship(this);
    this.enemy_spaceship_group = this.physics.add.group();
    this.enemy_spaceship_object = new Enemy_spaceship(this);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player_spaceship,this.enemy_spaceship_group,this.collision_player_enemy,null,this);
    this.power_up;
    this.power_up_object = new Power_ups(this);
    this.power_up_object.createpowerUp();
    
}
collision_player_enemy(player, enemy) { //parameters tells the function the objects that will collide
    this.player_spaceship_object.damage();
    this.enemy_spaceship_object.resetShip(enemy);
}
movebackground(bool = "") {
    this.background.tilePositionY = (bool === true) ? this.background.tilePositionY += 1 : this.background.tilePositionY -= 1;
}
update() {
    this.player_spaceship_object.update();    
    this.enemy_spaceship_object.update();
    this.power_up_object.update();
    this.movebackground();
}
}
```

Comment: try setInterval, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: tried it doesnt work either

Comment: how did it fail? you got error? please post your code

Comment: *"doesn't work either"* ... well it is the correct tool for the job so show us what you actually tried along with errors encountered If you read the documentation will also see there is a clearInterval() method. Also see how to create  [mcve]

Comment: As you have a loop just take the delta of Date.now() and the last saved time in ms

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple options with Phaser 3.

First, you could certainly add some logic to the built-in `update()` functionality in the scene. However, if you do so you'll need to manually keep track of the last time you added a powerup, and when you need to add another one.

For example, you might add a property to the scene to track the next time a powerup should be added, and then if the current time is equal to or after that, create a powerup, and then update the property value (current time + 1 minute).

An easier method is likely to use Phaser 3's built-in timer functionality.

On your scene, add a property to keep track of the [`TimerEvent`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Time.TimerEvent.html), as this will allow you to later pause or stop it.

Next, in the scene's `create()` create the timer event.

TypeScript example:

```
export default class MainGame extends Phaser.Scene {
    // Store the timer so we can access it later.
    private triggerTimer: Phaser.Time.TimerEvent;

    public create(): void {
        // ...
        this.triggerTimer = this.time.addEvent({
            callback: this.timerEvent,
            callbackScope: this,
            delay: 60000, // 1000 = 1 second
            loop: true
        });
        // ...
    }

    public timerEvent(): void {
        console.log('timerEvent');
        // Create your new object here.
    }
}
```

Either way, in your game sprite you should remove the functionality in `update()` that triggers `hi()`, as this effectively results in your sprites creating new timers every time the scene (and therefore each sprite) updates.

If you want an event to trigger x seconds after a sprite is created, you should define the timer (via `setInterval` or a Phaser timer) in the `constructor` instead.

Comment: This is "The Phaser Way" to use timers. Easy to use and works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setInterval`,
See example hope it will help you.

```js
function update(){
  console.log("your code");
}

setInterval(update, 2000);
```

Comment: I know with setInterval should work, but the problem is that its inside a infinite loop, something like this:

while (true) {
   run()
}

run() { setInterval (console.log("hi"), 5000)}

at the beggining it will wait 5 seconds, but once in prints hi, it wont stop

Comment: Post your complete block of code with loop for better understanding

Comment: posted :), hope can help me!

Answer (score 1):

I stringly recommend using requestAnimationFrame in order to have a slightly better timing between your UI and logic.

```
function powerUpEveryMinute() {
  // powerUp!!!!
  setTimeout(() => {
     requestAnimationFrame(powerUpEveryMinute);
  }, 60000);
}
requestAnimationFrame(powerUpEveryMinute);
```

This will call the animationFrame API. First it runs your power up, waits 1 minute and then calls the animationFrame API again with the same function and power up will be called 1 minute after this first one.

Let me know if this works